# Angular2 routing and component doesn't work

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend

I'm learning AngularJS I'm trying to do something with routes. I based on the hero tutorial from johnpapa on GitHub. I'm trying to load the UserComponent when the route its http://host/users but it seems doesn't work. When I enter the /users resource I get the "Loading..." And redirect to root.

Comment: What server are you using? You could try to switch to `HashLocationStrategy` by adding `{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}` to `providers: [...]` of `AppModule`.

Comment: i use the angular-cli to generate the application, so i use ng server but its works on node, no?

Comment: I don't know, I only use Dart. If `HashLocationStrategy` fixes it, we know for sure, if not, it's caused by something else.

Comment: I use HashLocationStrategy like u suggest (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/HashLocationStrategy-class.html) and doesnt seems do nothing for my problem.

Comment: Why did you comment `app-root` tag?

Comment: Do you see any errors in browser console?

Comment: yes i see errors on console.. "Error: moduleId should be a string in "UserComponent". See url for more information.
If you're using Webpack you should inline the template and the styles, see url" i will get this info for try solve it. thanks!

Comment: Try `template: require('./user.component.html')` instead of `templateUrl: './user.component.html'` Or just use string. And return `app-root` tag in your html

Comment: Or remove `moduleId`

Comment: You might actually get some helpful responses if you showed your code. A StackBlitz example demonstrating your issue would be most helpful.